# How to upload Video to Facebook: graph api v4

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, video

```
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[video exportPath]]];
    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"])
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                      initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" parameters:@{@"message":,@"source":videoData,@"contentType":@"multipart/form-data"} HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [mUpLoadRequestConnection addRequest:request
                          completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                  if (error == nil) 
                                 //
                                  else
                                 //

                              });
                          }];
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            [mUpLoadRequestConnection start];
            }
}
```

This is my code to upload a video to Facebook. But its not getting uploaded. Instead its giving error saying,

```
  error =         {
        code = 352;
        message = "(#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

Please suggest where am I wrong?

Comment: i would love it if someone helped because i am also struggling with this